# Create a single DF from multiple DFs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If anyone can help, I would like to create a single DF from multiple DFs.

This is my code, so far..

```
from functools import reduce

# Function responsible for making a query that returns a DB count and whether they are MATCHED or UNMATCHED.
def get_count(field,cdw_field,table,cdw_table,condition):
    query = f"""
    SELECT '{field}',count(a.{field}) as COUNT_MX, sum(CASE WHEN a.{field} = c.{cdw_field} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MATCHED,
    sum(CASE WHEN a.{field}<> IFNULL(c.{cdw_field},'99999') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UNMATCHED
    FROM {table} a
    LEFT JOIN {cdw_table} c ON a.MurexRootContractId = c.MurexRootContractId {condition};
    """
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
#     display(df)
    return df


# call the function with the parameters
portfolio = get_count('Portfolio','Portfolio',"coreTrades_eod", "cdw_eod", "AND a.TradeStatus = 'Live'")
buySell = get_count('BuySell','BuySell','coreTrades_eod','cdw_eod', "AND a.TradeStatus = 'Live'")
ContractPrice = get_count('ContractPrice','Price','coreTrades_eod','cdw_eod', f"AND a.TradeStatus = 'Live' AND {conditions_price}")
counterparty = get_count('MurexCounterpartyRef','Counterparty','coreTrades_eod','cdw_eod',"AND a.TradeStatus = 'Live'")

# Make unique DataFrame
dfs = [portfolio,buySell,ContractPrice,counterparty]
df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right),dfs)
display(df)

# Output -> These are the DF header.
'Portfolio' 'BuySell'   'ContractPrice' 'MurexCounterpartyRef'  COUNT_MX    MATCHED UNMATCHED
```

But, I would like to have DF formatted this way:

```
  'Field_Name'    COUNT_MX      MATCHED   UNMATCHED
0   Portfolio     15800          15177      623
1   BuySell1      5800           15177      623
2 ContractPrice   15800          15177      623
```

I wonder if this is possible, because the name 'Portfolio'in the above example will change with each function execution, i.e. the header of the next column will be 'BuySell', for example.

If anyone has a suggestion for doing it differently, please let me know I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate your dfs (horizontal):

```
dfs= pd.concat([portfolio,buySell,ContractPrice,counterparty], axis=1)
```

Otherwise you should put `axis = 0`

And may what you need is just to transpose:

```
dfs.T
```